# How to prevent from auto scroll to top when ion-list is updated

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll, ionic4

I have an ion-list like this :

```
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item lines="none" color="transparent" *ngFor="let conversationChatroom of conversationChatrooms"  (click)="openChatroom(conversationChatroom)">
         <chatroom-bloc [chatroom]="conversationChatroom"></chatroom-bloc>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

In the .ts file, I update the conversationChatroom's array every 5 secondes (get data from API to check new unread messages...).

When new datas are replaced into conversationChatroom, the list is refreshed and it auto scroll the view to the top. So, for exemple,  when the user is at the last chatroom (he has scroll to the bottom), the view auto scroll to Top.

How can I prevent this scroll ?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I'm also stuck with this.

Comment: @MeetuU yeah but the answer below didn't help me. I don't remember exactly what I did but I know that I had to change the conception instead of just adding some code. Sorry I don't have much more informations

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. It is a bug in ionic framework and there is a workaround for it. Add **trackBy:trackId** in the for loop.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages;trackBy:trackId" >
    <p> {{ msg.Text }} </p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and on the Component page, add below

```
trackId(index: number, fieldObject: any) {
    return fieldObject.id;
  }
```

Credit: [Ionic Bug report](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/22775)

Comment: I knew this, but always forgetting it, since it is a weird bug and not understanding why the don't fix it yet?!. thanks for answering it :D

Answer (score -1):

I needed the same feature for a chat application.

I used a turnaround by rescrolling to the bottom of the list each time I added a message to the list.

In your code, add:

```
@ViewChild('content', { static: false }) content: any;
```

`content` is the list ID.

Just after adding your item to the list, call this:

```
setTimeout(() => this.scrollToBottom(), 250); // wait for the list to be locally updated and rendered before scrolling, can be shorter
```

And the function itself:

```
  scrollToBottom() {
    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);  // 300ms animation speed
  }
```

The animation speed is setup to have a smooth effect.